# NgxExtendedPdfViewer can be displayed on the whole page, but not on parts of the page

Tags: angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

So this is possible:
[image]

If i add the Viewer in a smaller window (like a dialogue), this is happening:
[image]

Also, I didn't find a possibility to access viewport.scale.
Any ideas?